# Backendless column with data type double will result to a nil value

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I have a table in backendless which has 2 columns (latitude and longitude) with double data type.

In my class, `BlTable` I have this 2 fields

```
var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?
```

My backendless query is this:

```
 let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
 query.whereClause = "latitude IS NOT NULL AND longitude IS NOT NULL"
 backendlessInstance.persistenceService.of(Post.ofClass()).find(query,
    response: { blPosts in
      guard let posts = blPosts.data as? [Post] else {
        reject(BackendlessError.InvalidTypeForObject(name: "Post"))
        return
      }

      fulfill(posts)
    },
    error: { fault in
      reject(BackendlessError.ReceivedFault(fault))
  })
```

When I logged the value for the latitude and longitude, it returned a `nil` value. I've checked with my backendless data the column lat and long are filled.

Are there other things that needs to be considered here?

Answer (score 0):

Got the double value. But what I did was to set the data type of the Swift Entity to `NSNumber` and then use `.doubleValue`

Comment: The docs say "For Swift data objects, the Bool, Int, Double and Float types must not be declared optional"

https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_data_object.htm

Comment: @xissburg, that's right. In the original post, he has the following declaration:
var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?

Answer (score 0):

in Backendless fields of types Int, Double, Float and Bool cannot be optional, they must be initialized:
https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_data_object.htm

Comment: I  had to set the latitude and longitude to nil since it is optional in the first place. But thanks for the link.